# Python's dill one-time use of default argument in a defaultdict

Tags: python, lambda, pickle, dill

I'm trying to wrap my head around this odd problem that I'm facing. Let's say that we have a following instance of the `defaultdict` object:

```
import dill
from collections import defaultdict

a = 1
b = 2
default_value = a/b

dict_with_default = defaultdict(lambda: default_value)

dict_with_default['a'] = 1.2
dict_with_default['b'] = 3.5
dict_with_default['c'] = 0.25
```

Let's look how the dictionary looks like:

```
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x7f860c97be18>, {'a': 1.2, 'b': 3.5, 'c': 0.25})
```

Before saving to a `dill` object I want to check if the dictionary works correctly - it does and `'d'` is added:

```
print("d: ", dict_with_default['d'])
```

The dictionary looks like this now:

```
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x7f860c97be18>, {'a': 1.2, 'b': 3.5, 'c': 0.25, 'd': 0.5})
```

Since I **must** save a dictionary to a file (in order to transfer it to a different script) I save it to a `dill` object:

```
with open('./pickles/simple_dict_dill.p', 'wb') as file:
    dill.dump(dict_with_default, file, protocol=dill.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

Let's now turn our attention to the different script I've mentioned:

```
import dill

with open('./pickles/simple_dict_dill.p', 'rb') as file:
    simple_dict_dill = dill.load(file)

print("a:", simple_dict_dill['a'])
print("d:", simple_dict_dill['d'])
print("e:", simple_dict_dill['e']) # gives error
```

The line `print("e:", simple_dict_dill['e'])` gives the following error even though absent key access is handled by the `lambda: default_value`:

```
NameError: name 'default_value' is not defined
```

I thought `dill` can serialize lambda functions but it turns out there's a problem with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the `dill` author.  It's due to how a `lambda` is serialized when defined outside the global dictionary.  You can avoid this error in two ways:  (1) use the `recurse` setting, or (2) define the lambda in the global dict with no dangling pointers.

For example:

```
>>> import dill
>>> dill.settings['recurse'] = True
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> a = 1
>>> b = 2
>>> f = lambda: a/b
>>> d = defaultdict(f)
>>> d['a'] = 3
>>> d['b'] = 4
>>> dill.dumps(d)
b'\x80\x03ccollections\ndefaultdict\nq\x00cdill._dill\n_create_function\nq\x01(cdill._dill\n_load_type\nq\x02X\x08\x00\x00\x00CodeTypeq\x03\x85q\x04Rq\x05(K\x00K\x00K\x00K\x02KCC\x08t\x00t\x01\x1b\x00S\x00q\x06N\x85q\x07X\x01\x00\x00\x00aq\x08X\x01\x00\x00\x00bq\t\x86q\n)X\x07\x00\x00\x00<stdin>q\x0bX\x08\x00\x00\x00<lambda>q\x0cK\x01C\x00q\r))tq\x0eRq\x0f}q\x10(h\x08K\x01h\tK\x02uh\x0cNN}q\x11tq\x12Rq\x13\x85q\x14Rq\x15(h\x08K\x03h\tK\x04u.'
```

Then I cut-N-paste the string that's produced (instead of writing to a file... it's the same thing) into a new python session.

```
$ python
Python 3.6.9 (default, Jul  6 2019, 02:58:03) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dill
>>> d = dill.loads(b'\x80\x03ccollections\ndefaultdict\nq\x00cdill._dill\n_create_function\nq\x01(cdill._dill\n_load_type\nq\x02X\x08\x00\x00\x00CodeTypeq\x03\x85q\x04Rq\x05(K\x00K\x00K\x00K\x02KCC\x08t\x00t\x01\x1b\x00S\x00q\x06N\x85q\x07X\x01\x00\x00\x00aq\x08X\x01\x00\x00\x00bq\t\x86q\n)X\x07\x00\x00\x00<stdin>q\x0bX\x08\x00\x00\x00<lambda>q\x0cK\x01C\x00q\r))tq\x0eRq\x0f}q\x10(h\x08K\x01h\tK\x02uh\x0cNN}q\x11tq\x12Rq\x13\x85q\x14Rq\x15(h\x08K\x03h\tK\x04u.')
>>> d
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x101d8d048>, {'a': 3, 'b': 4})
>>> d['a']
3
>>> d['c']
0.5
>>>
```

IF you don't use the `recurse` setting, then you'd have to use:

```
>>> f = lambda: 1/2
>>> d = defaultdict(f)
```

when you create the defaultdict.

Of course, `dill` should be able to deal with the pointer references from a lambda better, but there are cases where it can't yet.